# Discord JDA How to make command be unique per user that uses it?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

In essence, I have an onGuildMessageReceived method that listens for a command **alarm** with which a user can set a countdown to notify him with a message. They type a time amount and eventual alarm message that comes with the ping they will get after that time.

My question is, how can I make this feature work for each user separately, so other users don't overwrite previous alarm times that were already ticking?

This method is called in the main code to start the countdown.

```
    public void StartTimer(int seconds, GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) 
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerReminder(event), seconds * 1000);
}
public void StartTimer(int seconds, GuildMessageReceivedEvent event, String text) 
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerReminder(event, text), seconds * 1000);
}
```

I have this subclass that does a block of code after the .schedule() time.

```
class TimerReminder extends TimerTask{
    GuildMessageReceivedEvent eventtrigger;
    String alarmText = "";
    private TimerReminder(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) 
    {
        eventtrigger=event;
    }
    private TimerReminder(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event, String alarmArg) 
    {
        eventtrigger=event;
        alarmText=alarmArg;
        
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        if(alarmText.isEmpty()) 
        {
            eventtrigger.getChannel().sendMessage("<@"+auth+">, ***your alarm is ringing!***").queue();
            timer.cancel(); // Terminate the timer thread
            
        }
        else 
        {
            eventtrigger.getChannel().sendMessage("<@"+auth+">:\n"+alarmText).queue();
            timer.cancel(); // Terminate the timer thread
            alarmText="";
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of each task, you're running cancel on the `timer` reference which cancels not the timer that is currently running (Unless no one else ran the command) but rather the timer object that is assigned at the moment to the `timer` reference which makes it seem like the timers are overwriting each other.

And even if you kept a reference to all of the timers so you could cancel them, there's no need for you to cancel the timer after the task completes, the timer terminates itself.

Furthermore, there's no need for you to keep a static reference to the timer that is currently running, or keep a reference to them at all. When you create a timer a background thread keeps a reference to the timer and the task so they won't get garbage collected. You'd be better off creating the timer as a local variable when the command is run, scheduling the timer and that's it.
If you want the ability to cancel the timers by a different command or whatever you have in mind, then you should keep a list or map with references to all the current timers so you can cancel them if needed.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes sense now! Well yes, I had in mind to add a cancel option and Your answer gave me guidance for completing the rest of the feature. Thank you for your time and effort in helping me out!